# Skimming another website for data to display in iPhone App (will apple approve app? )

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am thinking of putting together an app that will be pulling data from a very popular website. I have already looked at search and responses from the site and believe it can be done.

The only one question I have is, will apple have a problem with me doing this? The website more than likely will NOT give me permission to skim, but its public information so....  Will apple reject my app because I am skimming another site for data?

I would setup my own server to do the skimming but I am sure this website will see my ip hitting their servers a billion time a day (hopefully :) and ban my ip, so I plan on having the iphone itself skim the site.

Comment: whats the difference from the user just browsing the site themselves?

Comment: The same reason chase.com and other banks have an app. Ease of use and concentrated data. :)

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, because it's more of an issue with licensing content.  That said, does it seem right to you to use data from another site in a way that they would not want you to?  It seems like you want to make money off of someone else's work without their approval.

Comment: It's not with licensing at all- and who said anything about making money? It's going to be a free app-

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about app-store policy, not programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple only reject apps like this if they scrape Apple websites. Apple aren't bothered if you scrape someone else's site.

Answer (score 4):

Apple probably won't have an issue with this, but the website probably will.  Most websites hate scrapers and put it in their terms of service that you're not allowed to scrape.