# iPhone web services NSURL

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, webservices-client

hi I am working on an application which takes data from a website and it displays it in table. I have been sucessful in making like an RSS feed (made like a twitter feed so I think it is an xmlparser) but now I want to get data from a website which doesn't have RSS feed in it..I just want to get the titles from the webpage.... any suggestion how do I do it without the XMLParser...

thanks

Comment: I think you're talking about screen scraping which is "bad" and will be rejected. Can you disclose what site you're talking about? Most likely the data fueling the site is coming from an XML feed already.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to create on your server a php/asp/... page that will scrape data from the remote website.

Then, in that page, you can use some CURL to scrape data.
[See here](http://www.merchantos.com/blog/makebeta/php/scraping-links-with-php).

Next, you return the data in the format you want (XML/jSon/etc...).

Finally, you can easily call that script from your code.

On the other hand, pay attention to not scrape anything as skimming is generally illegal and Apple ca reject your app because of that.
There is a [nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199543/skimming-another-website-for-data-to-display-in-iphone-app-will-apple-approve-ap) talking about it.